# High Quality Image Magnification on GPU

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing

I'm looking for interesting algorithms for image magnification that can be implemented on a gpu for real-time scaling of video. Linear and bicubic interpolations algorithms are not good enough.

Suggestions?

Here are some papers I've found, unsure about their suitability for gpu implementation.

[Adaptive Interpolation](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v31/v31-16.pdf)

[Level Set](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.86.6241%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=IPvJTPTOGo3vsgavtO2XDg&usg=AFQjCNE7JnioswWJmyGS6B9LRGBQEZF9qA&sig2=nlnQfQ8Y_PMXz57gkq4iTA)

I've seen some demos on the cell processor used in TVs for scaling which had some impressive results, no link unfortunately.

Comment: i dont know exacly what you asking here

Comment: I'm with Svisstack.. are you developing for CUDA? ATI Stream? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to implement real-time high quality image magnification for video playback using opengl. However, I'm unsure what kind of image magnification techniques there are and which are suitable for implementation on the gpu, and now I'm asking for suggestions. Did that clear it up a  bit?

Comment: What do you mean by "implementation on the GPU"?

Comment: ehm... not on cpu? an opengl fragment shader...

Comment: What you need is one of those CSI computers that can 'enhance' a twelve-pixel image to a perfect image of a face! </sarcasm>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Super Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution) Algorithms. [Starting Point on CiteseerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/search?q=super+resolution&submit=Search&sort=rel)

Comment: @ronag I would be interested to have your feedback on SR if you eventually use it for realtime video magnification. For me SR is only interesting if you have multiple, perfectly aligned, images of the same scene.

Comment: @Ugo I have seen a demo of a SR implementation. They were able to align the images using correspondences (SIFT, etc) and affine transformations. The results were quite impressive. But I doubt that is was done in real time, they only showed the input images and the result.

Comment: I saw that also. Results are crazy ! like in CSI ;)

Answer (score 3):

`lanczos3` is a very nice interpolation algorithm (you can test it in the GIMP or virtualDub). It generally performs better than cubic interpolation and can be parallelized.
A GPU based version is implemented in Chromium:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47447
Check out chromium source code.

It may be still too slow for realtime video processing but maybe worth trying if you don't use too high resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try out CUVI Lib which offers a good set of GPU acceleration Image Processing algorithms. Find about it on: http://www.cuvilib.com

Disclosure: I am part of the team that developed CUVI.

Answer (score 1):

Still slightly 'work in progress' but [gpuCV](https://picoforge.int-evry.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Gpucv/Web/) is a drop in replacement for the openCV image processing functions implemented in openCL on a GPU

Answer (score 1):

Prefiltered cubic b-spline interpolation delivers good results (you can have a look [here](http://dannyruijters.nl/docs/cudaPrefilter3.pdf) for some theoretical background).
CUDA source code can be downloaded [here](http://dannyruijters.nl/cubicinterpolation/CI.zip).
WebGL examples can be found [here](http://www.dannyruijters.nl/cubicinterpolation/webgl/).

edit: The cubic interpolation code is now available on github: [CUDA](https://github.com/DannyRuijters/CubicInterpolationCUDA) version and [WebGL](https://github.com/DannyRuijters/CubicInterpolationWebGL) version.